# Function definition with default value (c++)

Tags: c++

Consider the following class:

```
class A{
public:
    void fun(int i=0) {cout<<"Base::fun("<<i<<")";}
};
```

If I understand correctly, when the compiler sees `void fun(int i=0)`, it will define 2 functions for us. One is the function:

```
void fun() {cout<<"Base::fun("<<0<<")";}
```

And the other one is the function:

```
 void fun(int i) {cout<<"Base::fun("<<i<<")";}
```

Next, as I understand, we cannot define 2 functions with the same name in a class. For example:

```
class A{
public:
    void fun() {cout<<"Base::fun()";}
    void fun() {cout<<"Base::fun("<<0<<")";}
};
```

does not compile and returns error:

```
error: 'void A::fun()' cannot be overloaded with 'void A::fun()'
```

So, my question is why does the following definition compiles :

```
class A{
public:
    void fun() {cout<<"Base::fun()";}
    void fun(int i=0) {cout<<"Base::fun("<<i<<")";}
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *it will define 2 functions for us* That's not really true.  What it does do is calls of `fun()` become `fun(0)`.

Comment: Read [function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading)

Comment: When I try to compile I get `15:11: error: call of overloaded 'fun()' is ambiguous`

Comment: If you try to actually use `fun` with no arguments, you do get a [compiler error](https://godbolt.org/z/79hcMrscW). Not sure why just compiling the class definition itself isn't sufficient to cause an error there, but maybe it's because it wasn't considered worth diagnosing "you wrote an ambiguous set of function overloads, then never called the functions" separately from "you attempted to call a function with an ambiguous overload set"

Comment: @FlorinC. What compiler do you use?

Comment: GCC, but I think it doesn't matter. I did called the function.

Comment: Interesting fun fact: the handling of the default value occurs at the call site based on the declaration of the function visible to the caller. If there are defaults for parameters, the compiler pops them in while calling the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I understand correctly, when the compiler sees void fun(int i=0), it will define 2 functions for us.

No you do not understand correctly. It only defines one single function returning void and taking an int parameter. Simply if you call it with no parameter and if not function with same name and declared with no parameter exists, the compiler will implicitely add the default parameter.

Said differently the compiler will under the hood replace this call:

```
fun();
```

with that one:

```
fun(0);
```

Comment: This is interesting, as the ambiguity becomes apparent only when calling the function.

Comment: @FlorinC. That might be because calling `fun (42)` would be legal.

Comment: The distinction is made even clearer when using `virtual`. You can provide different default argument values for overrides, and the value used depends on the static pointer type, not the object's dynamic type. If the functions were duplicated without the argument, it couldn't mix the default values of one type with the override of another type. Godbolt : https://godbolt.org/z/GzKMM9eY3

Comment: @PaulSanders Would it? See my edit

Comment: Hmm, seems that your edit has been rolled back.  But I see what you mean, must be something to do with deriving from `Base`.